# From Python to Ruby

Tags: python, ruby

I am rewriting one case from Python to Ruby, and have a problem.
The program reads data from terminal "python test.py 1010010101"

```
def to_str(data):
"""Helper function to convert lists and sets to string.
Args:
    data (LIST, SET): list or set to convert
Returns:
    STRING: result string
"""
if isinstance(data, list):
    res = ''.join([str(i) for i in data])
elif isinstance(data, set):
    res = ''.join(data)
return res
```

Almost done it on Ruby, but have "Undefined method 'join' for # 
Tryed .to_a, which doesn't help.

My Ruby's code:

```
def to_str(data)
    if data.is_a? Array
       res = data.map &:to_s.join('')
    elsif data.is_a? Set
       res = data.join('')
    end
    return res
  end
```

Comment: That Python code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It's a module from this code https://gist.github.com/quarckster/d7661f26f71b302e1052

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
2.2.2 :001 > require 'set'                                                                                                                                                                               
 => true 
2.2.2 :002 > [1, 2, "test"].join                                                                                                                                                                         
 => "12test" 
2.2.2 :003 > Set.new([1, 2, "test"]).to_a.join                                                                                                                                                           
 => "12test"
```

Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't exactly have the reasoning behind why, but you need to wrap the `map` enumerator argument in parentheses like below, or else it will see the symbol `:to_s` and try to use the `join` method on that alone. (i.e.: NoMethodError: undefined method `join' for :to_s:Symbol)

```
def to_str(data)
  if data.is_a? Array
    res = data.map(&:to_s).join('')
  elsif data.is_a? Set
    res = data.join('')
  end
return res
end
```

Edit: It might have something to do with `&:to_s` being a proc

Comment: You're fix is working, but now it undefined method from second join

Comment: @JackBacke The following should fix it: `res = data.to_a.join('')`. I've never worked with `Set` objects before, but looks similar to an array except it is an object type with a unique set of methods. Look here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html for a list of methods for `Set` objects